# How to check if a message author has a role?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to code a bot for a game idea my friends and I have. The command I'm working on is the score adjuster. Obviously though, I only want moderators to have access to this command.

I have read several threads and tried several methods to check for a role though, and all close the script with this error:

```
if (message.member.roles.has(modRole))
```

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'roles')

This is the last code I tried:

```js
bot.on("message", (message) => {
    let args = message.content.toLowerCase().substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    if (args[0] === "adjust" && args[1] !== "help") {
        if (message.member.roles.has("modRoleID")) {
            // Adjust command here
        }
    }
});
```

Why is the bot not able to read .roles()?

Comment: What discord.js version are you on? Is the command being run in DMs?

Comment: @Palm According the the list command, I am running discord.js@11.4.2 - I recently installed it though, so I'm not sure why I'm not running the most recent version. Everything else works about the bot works fine, but I guess I'm trying to use updated methods with the outdated language. Command is being run in a server text channel

Comment: @Palm So I went back and looked at the v11 documentation. Even doing it the way specified in the FAQ, it returns the same error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading roles')`

Comment: Please update to the most recent version. Just because something works, does not mean everything works.

Answer (score 0):

So I never got .roles to work. And I wasn't about to recode the entire bot to match v13, so here's what I did:

I just set an array to contain all the moderator user id's, and then checked if the author was a moderator, like so:

```
const mods = ['userID_1','userID_2'];

bot.on("message", (message) => {

    let args = message.content.toLowerCase().substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    if (args[0] === "adjust" && args[1] !== "help") {
        if (!mods.includes(message.author.id)) return message.channel.send("You do not have permission to use that command!").then()
        //Adjust command here
    }
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).